# Tracking a dropdown field selection in Contact Form 7 with Google Analytics

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, contact-form-7

I have a WordPress site using Contact Form 7. We have events tracking set up with the following code in the head:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
ga('send', 'event', 'Contact Form', 'submit');
}, false );
</script>
```

One of the forms we are tracking has a dropdown field to select the type of enquiry. (e.g. "General Enquiry" or "Request a Visit")

Is it possible to track this field in Analytics so we can separate out type of enquiry?

We don't currently have Google Tag Manager set up, so we're just relying on the script passing data through to Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

You could add some JavaScript above your event code to determine which field is selected when the form is submitted and then pass that in as your event label since no event label currently exists.